# Any beaches along the New York - Boston corridor?

Tags: road-trips, beaches, boston, new-york-city

I want to stop between Boston and New York for a day on my travel to go swimming near a sandy beach, traveling by car. Are there convenient places located along the route?

Comment: Sea? River? Lake? Olympic Pool? No preference?

Comment: A sandy beach on the ocean would be great. This will be my last day before traveling back and I want to relax a little bit :) .

Comment: How are you travelling? Car?

Comment: I am travelling by car.

Comment: Why closed? This seems specific enough to be answerable, and I don't see what's so unconstructive about it.

Comment: @jonik: I edited the question (incorporating the OP's comments), and it may now be answerable in its current form. See the associated Meta question I asked. http://meta.travel.stackexchange.com/questions/301/how-do-we-make-questions-like-what-do-i-do-when-i-get-to-destination-x-good-fo  You and I don't have quite enough reputation (500) to vote to reopen, but we both may shortly.

Comment: @Tom: Yeah, I only noticed after commenting that originally the question was a bit more vague...

Comment: Hopefully more vote to reopen it.

Comment: There is still no `right` answer for this question - only list of recommendation. And question is still very broad - there are a lot of such places for sure. All interested in this question can disscuss it in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: seems like there are a *lot* of views on this question which would tell me this may be one to reopen. without a doubt if the guidelines were a little different.

Comment: Hammonasset State Park in Connecticut is about one mile away from Route 95.  There's about 2 miles of lovely sandy beach here.  It can be very busy on weekends.  Entry is not free.  Details here: http://www.ct.gov/deep/cwp/view.asp?a=2716&q=325210&deepNav_GID=1650

Comment: I agree with @jagular's comment / recommendation, it is where I would go if I had your itinerary.